# Windows and Linux installation (same laptop)

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, installation

I need help and advice about this situation.

I have an old laptop, I would say low-end performce laptop with 2 GB of RAM and only 32 GB of eMMC drive.
It's an old laptop but what I love about this laptop is that it came with Windows 8 pre-installed and I didn't have
any problems with that Windows for years. The main advantage I often use is Windows Recovery Options because when I install some
weird software or virus or I feel lack of performance I just run that Windows Recovery Option, select "**Clean the drive fully**",
it takes about 20 minutes to set back that Windows 8 system to the clean start (no installation key is needed, Windows is already activated every time after Recovery).

Now the situation is I need Linux because I need to use some software that only exists in Linux environments.

- I've already tried Virtual machines in which I can install Linux distribution, that works ... but I'm facing performance problems
  because of lack of hardware resources of that small laptop.
- I've also tried to make LiveUSB flash drive installation of some Linux distributions, but again, the performance is too bad (sometimes even mouse cursor movements are blocked or lagging).

---

1. Is there any other way to install Linux on that laptop without loosing that Windows 8 which is already installed?
   I really don't want now to loose current Windows because of Linux and later re-install Windows all the time and bother with their Product/Installation/Activation keys.
2. Is there any way to divide 32 GB of eMMC drive in 2 parts? First part with current installed Windows 8 and second part with Linux distro.
3. Is this possible, if yes how to do that?
4. How much GB to leave for Windows, how much for Linux?
5. Am I going to loose current installed Windows 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it would be possible to have both on one drive in separate partitions (see this HTG [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/187789/dual-booting-explained-how-you-can-have-multiple-operating-systems-on-your-computer/) and [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/aicq5n/install_2_oss_on_1_hard_drive_dual_boot/)).

The main thing I would worry about is your storage. 32 gigs aren't much. Windows 8 is around [13 gigs](https://www.intowindows.com/windows-8-install-size/) alone. Say the Linux distro was Ubuntu. Ubuntu isn't [nearly as big as Windows](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Installing_Ubuntu_on_a_Windows_System_(Dual_booting)#:%7E:text=According%20to%20the%20Ubuntu%20documentation,during%20your%20first%20system%20update.), but it'll get bigger over time. Depending on what you're doing on your laptop, you're going to run out of space. Even if it's working fine right now, after you install the software you want on your Linux distro, you're not going to have much space left. For some people, this is fine, but for people like me who work with files all the time, it might be an issue.

As for your RAM, it will probably be slow, but adding another OS doesn't affect the RAM, as it's volatile and only stores information while it's powered on, and even then only information the CPU needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I decided to install Lubuntu.